# How to filter different values from a specific column?

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I have a code:

```
SELECT *
from (select rank() over(partition by color_id order by rand(101)) as rank_nr,* 
FROM table1

WHERE action_code_is in(SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE action_code_is = 'pink' LIMIT 4)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE action_code_is = 'yellow' LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE action_code_is = 'blue' LIMIT 6)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE action_code_is = 'green'LIMIT 3)

order by color_id)a 
WHERE rank_nr<=18
```

The main thing that I have thousands of data (action_code_is) and every color_id has all these action_code_is. I need to filter only 18 results of each color_id(also have many data) in which would be included only pink, yellow, blue, green values and only with set quantity.

I know that code does not look well, and I know that there are mistakes, because it does not work for me. But I am very fresh here and cannot find solution. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell what exact sql you are using for us to be able to give you proper answer, but no matter what sql is used you can look into how to join different select statements. **UNION ALL** should be helpful. In sql server it's used like this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 color FROM table1 WHERE color = 'blue' 
UNION ALL SELECT TOP 4 color FROM table1 WHERE color = 'red'
```

This query should give you 3 rows where the color is blue and 4 where the color is red.

Comment: thanks :/ but TOP 3/ TOP4 do not work. I use impala :/

Comment: Haven't used impala but according to [this][1] ordering by limit should do the trick.


  [1]: https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_limit.html